# Modifying aframe Cursor

Tags: html, aframe

So I made this so far as my cursor:

<a-entity  cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"

```
        position="0 0 -1"

        geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"

        material="color: black; shader: flat"

        id="cursor">

    </a-entity>
```

What I'm trying to do is change the radiusInner to 1 from 0.02 using jquery. I tried:

$("#cursor").attr("geometry","radiusInner","1");

and

$("#cursor").attr("geometry.radiusInner","1");

None of them work. How can you make a working one?

Comment: Full code to reproduce what you’re trying to achieve will help helpers to help you. Glitch is great https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: You don't really need full code. I just need to change an attr in an attr.

Comment: There are always nuances. If you share code you will be more likely to get a working answer you can quickly reuse. Remember that people volunteer their time to help you. The easier you can make it the better.